# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on Lenovo G50-70. Difficulties to create an extended partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, gparted

I bought recently a new computer; A Lenovo G50-70 and found that Windows 8 64bits was installed on it. I'm trying actually to remove Windows and replace it by Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64 bits. After creating a USB Live containing this version of Ubuntu, I booted through Legacy mode and tried Ubuntu so that I can access Gparted.

When I reached gparted, I found three ntfs partitions flagged respectively msftdata, msftdata and diag, one unknown partition flagged msftres and a fat32 partition flagged boot.

My aim is to remove them all and create an extended partition that will allow me to set up Ubuntu. However, when I removed the partitions in gparted and tried to create an extended partition I couldn't do so; Gparted was only allowing me to create a primary partition (Logical and Extended were grayed out and thus not selectable).

By the way, I found a small warning in the "partition" column near to Unknown and ntfs partitions. On the information window, it says that it isn't able to read the contents of the file system. "Because of this some operations may be unavailable. The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support : ntfsprogs/ntfs-3g." Is this related to my inability to create an extended partition ?

Comment: If you had UEFI Windows then you have gpt partitioning. One advantage of gpt is that there are only primary partitions. Ubuntu will boot from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI or CSM/BIOS, but for UEFI you need the ESP - efi system partition or for CSM a 1 or 2MB unformatted bios_grub partition. Windows only boots from gpt with UEFI. http://askubuntu.com/questions/629470/gpt-vs-mbr-why-not-mbr And: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Advantages_of_GPT

Answer (score 1):

if you delete all partitions then gparted will create a primary first before you can create extended, if you want to remove windoz completely create a primary partition for root and extended for home and swap if your computer has win 8 on it you probably have to go into the bios to disable eufi partition table before any partition software will work. a eufi partition is protected by the bios unless you change the default settings

Comment: Hello Ron Thill. Thank you for your answer. I think that I'll remove everything and then create a primary partition of 4GO for Linux swap (I've 4GO of RAM). I'll allocate what remains for the root.