# How to install bootable Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit RAID 5 with 4TB HDDs on an UEFI/GPT system?

Tags: boot, uefi, gpt, raid5

Is there any step by step instruction to install "bootable" software RAID5 with 3 HDD of 4TB each? 
I tried many way to install this. No problem install raid5 but I couldn't  boot.

(HDD: Seagate ST4000NE0025-2EW)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I made the installation of "bootable RAID5 with 4TB HDD" using the links below:

[How to install Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 64-bit with a dual-boot RAID 1 partition on an UEFI/GPT system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-16-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an?answertab=votes#tab-top)
[Should dual booting work from a 4TB HDD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879272/should-dual-booting-work-from-a-4tb-hdd)
[How to install Ubuntu server with UEFI and RAID1 + LVM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355727/how-to-install-ubuntu-server-with-uefi-and-raid1-lvm)

Attention! System must be booted with a UEFI media.

I created partition structure of each HDD is like below:

```
Device,          Size,   Type,               Description
/dev/sd[abc]1,    2MB,   ef02 (Grub-bios flag, Bios boot) 
/dev/sd[abc]2,  500MB,   ef00 (EFI system, ESP)
/dev/sd[abc]3,  500MB,   fd00 (Linux Raid),  md0 -> ext4 -> /boot 
/dev/sd[abc]4,   12GB,   fd00 (Linux Raid),  md1 -> swap -> /swap 
/dev/sd[abc]5,   15GB,   fd00 (Linux Raid),  md2 -> ext4 -> / 
/dev/sd[abc]6,  3.7TB,   fd00 (Linux Raid),  md3 -> ext4 -> /data
```

```
    mount /dev/md2 /mnt
    mount /dev/md0 /mnt/boot
    mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
    mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
    mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
    chroot /mnt

    apt-get install -y grub-efi-amd64
    apt-get install -y mdadm

    mount /dev/sda2 /boot/efi
    grub-install --boot-directory=/boot --boorloader-id=ubuntua --target=X86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --recheck
    umount /dev/sda2

    mount /dev/sdb2 /boot/efi
    grub-install --boot-directory=/boot --boorloader-id=ubuntub --target=X86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --recheck
    umount /dev/sdb2

    mount /dev/sdc2 /boot/efi
    grub-install --boot-directory=/boot --boorloader-id=ubuntuc --target=X86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --recheck
    umount /dev/sdc2

    efibootmgr
```

That's all for me. I hope it will be useful to those who need it.