# Moving part of my dual boot to SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

Currently I have a single 1TB HDD with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 17.10 installed. Now I've bought an SSD and now I'm facing a problem I can't find the answer for.
My plan is something like this:

1. Delete Ubuntu 17.10
2. Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on the SSD with some partitions on SSD and some on HDD
3. Somehow tell the newly installed GRUB how to boot Windows 7.

While I can manage task #1 just fine (duh!), and with some research #2 shouldn't be too big of an issue either. However, I have no idea about #3. Would grub just pick it up while being installed by Ubuntu's graphical installer, or would I have to do some config tinkering to make it work? What would I have to do in the second case?

EDIT: My Win7 is using BIOS boot, not UEFI.

Comment: Since Windows 7, almost sure to be BIOS boot on MBR partitioned drive. If you have newer UEFI hardware, you still need to install Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode to SSD. You may still want gpt, but then need bios_grub partition, if drive may in future be used with UEFI system. Then `sudo update-grub` will find & let you boot Windows. Also good idea to reinstall Windows boot loader to Windows drive and set BIOS to boot Ubuntu drive. only use Something Else install option. You should have most or all of Ubuntu on SSD and data at /mnt/data on HDD.

Comment: No idea what gpt is, will do some research. As for data partition, that's how I have it set up currently.

Comment: Gpt is not a huge advantage, but is required with newer UEFI systems (all in last 5 years). But it is more modern & has a backup partition table which has saved a few users.  See this for more info https://askubuntu.com/questions/629470/gpt-vs-mbr-why-not-mbr