# Is there any benefit in using UEFI GPT instead of Legacy MBR?

Tags: uefi, laptop, bios, gpt, mbr

Is there any benefit in using UEFI GPT instead of Legacy MBR?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The only reason now to use MBR, is if dual booting Windows with Windows in BIOS boot mode. It requires MBR. But Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot. Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/629470/gpt-vs-mbr-why-not-mbr Also: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Advantages_of_GPT

Comment: In summary, *is there any benefit...?* can be answered as Yes, all of them.

Comment: One big advantage of using GPT is that it's not prone to getting wiped out by a Windows major update... seriously... the major Windows updates tend to wipe MBR Linux disk partitions.