# How to move/resize partitions & take profit of available space

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Today I have installed a new Ubuntu system & I have deleted partition where old system was installed, after moving all relevant data. This is how I have my disk right now

[image: gparted screenshot]

New system is installed in **/dev/sda8**

**/dev/sda7** contains some other data I have

What I would like to do is using that unallocated 230G in /dev/sda8 (or /dev/sda7), is it possible? I have tried **Resize/Move** options in **gparted**, but I am not sure if I can do what I want

Another option would be just formatting that unallocated space as ext4, move the contents of **/dev/sda7**, and then deleting it, and then... could I resize **/dev/sda8** to gain that 100G of deleted **/dev/sda7**?

Comment: Question was more related to the position relevance of every partition & how to deal with it... So, for instance, /dev/sda8 isn't mounted, but I am not able to resize it

Comment: I suggest to backup all data that you want to keep (from `/dev/sda7` and `/dev/sda8`) and after that make a fresh installation of Ubuntu using the whole drive (and after that copy the files you want from the backup). The problems with the current partition table are 1. that your partitions are in an extended partition and 2. that if you move the head end of the root partition **`/'`**, the BIOS bootloader will fail, and you have to repair/reinstall grub. That is not a problem in UEFI mode.

Comment: You also are showing MBR partitioning with an ESP - efi system partition. Normally UEFI installs use gpt partitioning. Then no primary, extended & logical partitions, they all are in effect primary. You can convert, but some tools erase entire drive. See: Converting from MBR to gpt:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1454252
 Advantages: http://askubuntu.com/questions/629470/gpt-vs-mbr-why-not-mbr See Rod Smiths answer as he is author of gdisk.

Comment: I partially agree with both sudodus and oldfred's comments... however... I'd backup your important data, then boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, lay down a fresh partition table (GPT if you have a current UEFI computer, MBR if you have an older BIOS computer) (this will wipe the disk), then fresh reinstall Ubuntu, then restore your data. Much better long term results this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first I did was that "another option" I posted...

> Another option would be just formatting that unallocated space as ext4, move the contents of /dev/sda7, and then deleting it, and then... could I resize /dev/sda8 to gain that 100G of deleted /dev/sda7?

After that: boot from Live USB, open **gparted** & delete **/dev/sda7**

Now, the big mistake... :(

Drag & drop **/dev/sda6** to right. This was the only way (I think) to resize **/dev/sda8** with the 100G of deleted **/dev/sda7**

With this, I got the desired size of partitions but a broken grub (I suppose **/dev/sda6** position in disk was relevant), with nice **grub rescue** message when trying to boot the new system

How I fixed this? (after several tries... following some tutorials which didn't worked, and even trying to install a new Ubuntu alongside in free space, assuming that should *rebuild* grub... which didn't happened)

Again, boot from Live USB, open terminal and login as root `sudo -s`

(/dev/**sda** was used from Live system, so the partition with *working* system was /dev/**sdb8**)

```
mount /dev/sdb8 /mnt
grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdb
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb
```

Reboot, and... grub was working again :)