# Install grub from LiveUSB: Can't find efi directory

Tags: grub2, uefi, 19.10, grub-efi, grub-legacy

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. But [grub](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) can't install due to multiple mount  errors. I tried to install it from a LiveUSB, but `sudo chroot /mnt` fails with

```
#grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for x86_64 efi platform
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory
```

[image]

Please help me to solve this immediately

Comment: Immediately? Well, let's mosey on over and take a look. Well, doggies. I do wonder if /dev/sda  is partitioned for MBR or GPT?  https://askubuntu.com/a/629819/197910  Let's find out, shall we, 'cause that's reeeeel important if yer gonna do something which expected to find the EFI directory, don't ya know? Run `sudo blkid /dev/sda | grep  PTTYPE` then click [edit] and paste the result into your question. Don't use Add Comment because you lose your formatting on what you reply with in a Comment; instead, use [edit].

Comment: Hard to read your screen shot, but you have to mount ESP - efi system partition as part of chroot. UEFI chroot:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380

Comment: The problem starts with the first mount.  Control with `ls -al / | grep mnt` if the folder realy is not present.