# Correct partitions only show up in Disks, no other tool can read them

Tags: partitioning, gpt, mbr

Here's how my partitions show up in the Disks utility. Note that trying to manage them at all e.g. deleting one gives a `udisks-error-quark 0`
[image: Disks]

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong, so I can delete my swap & the "Data_Dump" partition, then extend my home. However it seems every other tool I try can't understand the partitions, and gives completely wrong output.

Parted:

```
parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA SSD 1TB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB  primary
 2      1049kB  650MB   649MB   primary  fat32        boot
 3      650MB   1000GB  1000GB  primary  ext4
```

fdisk

```
fdisk /dev/sda -l    
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: SSD 1TB         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x79572a60

Device     Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            63       2047       1985 992.5K 42 SFS
/dev/sda2  *       2048    1269759    1267712   619M 42 SFS
/dev/sda3       1269760 1953523119 1952253360 930.9G 42 SFS
```

What is wrong? Can anything be done to salvage this setup without wiping the disk?

Comment: Do you have `ldmtool` installed in your system? Looks like Windows dynamic disk, according to `ID` and `Type` in fdisk-output. Otherwise you couldn't have five primary partitions on the disk. Any chance to manage your partitions from within Windows?

Comment: I don't want to manage this disk in windows, I think I must have completely messed it up when I created the data partition.

Comment: I don't think I even want is as MBR, I think it must have somehow been automatically converted to MBR without informing me.

Comment: Best to undo dynamic (SFS) partitions. And if not using Windows, do not use NTFS as it will need chkdsk or other repairs that you cannot do from Linux. Other options also Aomei or even testdisk if only 4 dynamic partitions:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/482768/changing-windows-dynamic-disk-partition-to-basic-partition-and-not-the-full-driv Best to just start over and use gpt partitioning. See answer by Rod Smith author of gdisk. http://askubuntu.com/questions/629470/gpt-vs-mbr-why-not-mbr

Comment: Is there nothing that can be done from linux? I've never used the windows tools & don't really have any understanding of what these SFS partitions are. I was able to delete the "Data_Dump" partition in windows, but I don't know how to go from there to just a normal Linux disk.